# How do I correctly add worker nodes to my cluster?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, cluster-computing

I am trying to create a cluster with the following parameters on Google Cloud:

1. 1 Master
2. 7 Worker nodes
3. Each of them with 1 vCPU
4. The master node should get full SSD capacity and the worker nodes should get equal shares of standard disk capacity.

This is my code:

```
#Create the cluster
CLUSTER = '{}-cluster'.format(PROJECT)
!gcloud dataproc clusters create $CLUSTER \
    --image-version 1.5-ubuntu18 --single-node \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --master-boot-disk-type pd-ssd --master-boot-disk-size 100 \
    --num-workers 7 \
    --worker-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --worker-boot-disk-type pd-standard --worker-boot-disk-size 200 \
    --max-idle 3600s \
```

This is my error:

```
RROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) argument --single-node: At most one of --single-node | --num-secondary-workers --num-workers --secondary-worker-type can be specified.
```

Updated attempt:

```
#Create the cluster
CLUSTER = '{}-cluster'.format(PROJECT)
!gcloud dataproc clusters create $CLUSTER \
    --image-version 1.5-ubuntu18 \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --master-boot-disk-type pd-ssd --master-boot-disk-size 100 \
    --num-secondary-workers = 7 \
    --secondary-worker-type=non-preemptible \
    --secondary-worker-boot-disk-type pd-standard \
    --secondary-worker-boot-disk-size=200 \
    --max-idle 3600s \
    --initialization-actions=gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-$REGION/python/pip-install.sh \
    --metadata=PIP_PACKAGES=tensorflow==2.4.0
```

I don't follow what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation should help [`gcloud dataproc clusters create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create). It explains that:

- [`--single-node`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create#--single-node) says "Create a single node cluster" which is **not** what you want, so you don't want to include it.
- You want a "Multi-node cluster" so you want a combination of [`--num-secondary-workers`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create#--num-secondary-workers) and [`--num-workers`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create#--num-workers).

The documentation describes [Secondary workers](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/compute/secondary-vms)

Comment: Thanks a lot for coming back to me. I am not sure how to distinguish between number of workers and number of secondary workers - I have updated my code to what I think should be the case. Do I have to specify my master as being a 'num of workers'?